# dynamic column referencing- greenplum

Tags: sql, greenplum

I am trying to dynamically reference multiple column names in a query, and I am confused on how to achieve the same. Below, I am stating the problem situation and any tips on how to achieve this is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Problem statement:
I have a column reference table which contains the following attributes: Colname, colvalue, description. for reference purposes lets name this table Tablename:colref

I have a standard table: Tablename: Tasks

Now using colref I want to exclude certain records from the Tasks table
for ex. if there is an entry in colref table such as below- all records in Tasks table having the same value for that column should be excluded.

```
Colname:TaskType
Colvalue:Open
description: Excludes open tasks
```

Any tips on how to achieve the same?

Table Tasks:

```
 TaskID TaskName    Tasktype    TaskStatus  TaskOwner   Description
    1   abc         SR          New         jim         desc1
    2   xyz         SR          WIP         john        desc2
    3   qwe         CR          New         dave        desc3
    4   rty         SR          Closed      mike        desc4
    5   yui         CR          Closed      paul        desc5
```

Table: Colref

```
ColName    ColValue include  description
TaskStatus  New     true     all new tasks are included
Tasktype    CR      true     all CR tasks are included
```

Result table:

```
TaskID  TaskName    Tasktype    TaskStatus  TaskOwner   Description
   1    abc         SR          New         jim         desc1
   3    qwe         CR          New         dave        desc3
   5    yui         CR          Closed      paul        desc5
```

Basically I want to include only those conditons that are mentioned in the ColRef table. in this case only those thats that are New or are of type CR.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Show some actual code and sample data

Comment: updated with sample. any tips?

Comment: Youd would need a procedure to build dynamic SQL statement. Give it a try and let us know of your doubts.

Comment: Do u have any pointers? 

So here is my approach: I am thinking  about leveraging the information schema and get the colum names and its values into variables. 

I need to then iterative join the main table to the column names and its corresponding variable --> Any thoughts?